# Usage and meanings of 十分

Tags: words, usage, meaning

In English, "to have enough" has several different meanings. One of them is "to be fed up": If you have an argument and want to express that you're fed up and about to walk out of the room and you can say "Enough!" or "I've had enough of this.".

Can you say

（私は）十分にあった！

to express anger and fed-up-ness? Or does it only apply in the literal sense when you want to say you had enough to eat, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely use the word 十分 to finish an argument, like this (in the ascending order of politeness):

> - （もう）十分だ！
> - （もう）十分です！
> - （もう）十分でしょう。

「私は十分にあった」 would mean something like "There was a plenty of me", which is weird.

「私は十分だ」 would make sense, which sounds like "As for me, enough. (For others, let them keep arguing if they like)".

「もうたくさんだ！」 is another common set phrase for this situation.

Comment: While this is right for 十分, does this actually expressing "being fed up"?

Comment: I think "十分だ!" may well express the speaker is disgusted, though it largely depends on the tone of the voice. Unlike うんざりだ or たくさんだ which are always negative/offensive, 十分 might be used in a polite manner. 「もう十分でしょう、次の話題にうつりませんか?」

Answer (score -2):

Nah, doesn't work like that.　The most common and elegant translation is simply もういい。You can incorporate 十分 with expressions but they don't quite work colloquially as you posted.  That's to say, it can be used to express "fed upness" but works more like, "that's enough", but そこまでだ is going to be more common in such a scenario (when you're telling someone they need to cut the cord, so to speak).